# autoend .vbs when it runs .bat

Tags: batch, vbscript

I have [this script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54874471/how-to-run-more-than-one-batch-with-vbs-and-set-batch-file-path-using-environmen) and I need it to finish (auto-end or autokill itself and also close wscript.exe) after launching the .bat

```
On Error Resume next
If WScript.Arguments.Named.Exists("elevated") = False Then
      'Launch the script again as administrator
       CreateObject("Shell.Application").ShellExecute "wscript.exe", """" & WScript.ScriptFullName & """ /elevated", "", "runas", 1
       WScript.Quit
Else
      'Change the working directory from the system32 folder back to the script's folder.
      Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
      oShell.CurrentDirectory = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName)

End If

Dim Fso
Set Fso = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set objshell = createobject("wscript.shell")

homedrive = objshell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings( "%HOMEDRIVE%" )

SCRIPT = homedrive & "\test\bar.bat"
strPath = Wscript.ScriptFullName
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.GetFile(strPath)
strFolder = objFSO.GetParentFolderName(objFile)

NewPath = objFSO.BuildPath(strFolder, SCRIPT)
set objshell = createobject("wscript.shell")

objshell.Run (script),0,True
```

**Failed attempts:**

- I tried with [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13503840/what-is-the-code-to-exit-stop-vbscript-from-running-in-the-event-of-a-condition) and it did not work
- WScript.Quit (at the end of the script) and it did not work
- Change "true" to "False" and it did not work

Any ideas?

**Update**: The main problem is that wscript.exe remains running after launching the .vbs (it can be seen in the task manager) and i can not use cmd commands inside the .vbs or inside .bat (taskkill /f /im "wscript.exe" /t) because the .bat and the .vbs are closed

**If my question has no answer:** I would appreciate someone telling me how to launch a .bat with a method that Windows recognizes natively (without installing dependencies). Please exclude the following methods:

1. launch .bat directly
2. Launch .bat with a shortcut
3. Convert .bat to .exe
4. Launch .bat with .vbs

Comment: How are you starting the script?

Comment: @Appleoddity ?. double click on the .vbs

Comment: I don’t understand the purpose of your script. The way it is written it appears like it won’t function as you intend. A large portion of the script actually does absolutely nothing. This is what I’m talking about with Sanity checks. Get rid of all the code except the 4 lines responsible for running the batch file. I guarantee you wscript will end. It is obvious your code is opening another instance of wscript or dieing for some reason. But it is NOT because of the batch file. This is part of debugging your code. You’ve been given the answer specific to your question.

Comment: What the .vbs does is: 1. make sure that it runs with privileges 2. it calls the .bat in its "path of homedrive". 3. (without waiting) it must close the .vbs and its interpreter wscript.exe (this is the part doesn't work)

Comment: I understand the script. I’m saying it doesn’t function like you expect and a large portion of the code does actually nothing. The code is buggy and that is your problem. It is NOT a problem of wscript not finishing after running the .bat. I told you how to solve that issue.

Comment: You just said: "fix the code". If you think the problem is the code, I appreciate a more detailed explanation.

Comment: You’re not understanding the purpose of the forum. You ask a question with supporting details and someone provides an answer. I did provide an answer directly to your question and it will solve your issue. However, you have other code that is misbehaving and you just haven’t worked it out yet. I’m not here to debug your scripts for you. That is your job, no offense. I can see some code doesn’t do anything - it doesn’t even belong in there. I see it starts a new instance of wscript, maybe that is the issue. I don’t know why, and I don’t have the time to debug for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
On Error Resume next
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set objshell = createobject("wscript.shell")

homedrive = objshell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings( "%HOMEDRIVE%" )

SCRIPT = homedrive & "\test\bar.bat"

If WScript.Arguments.Named.Exists("elevated") = False Then
    'Launch the script again as administrator
    CreateObject("Shell.Application").ShellExecute "wscript.exe", """" & WScript.ScriptFullName & """ /elevated", "", "runas", 1
    WScript.Quit
Else
    'Change the working directory from the system32 folder back to the script's folder.
    objShell.CurrentDirectory = fso.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName)
End If

objshell.Run (script),0,False
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

```
objshell.Run (script),1,True
```

To:

```
objshell.Run (script),1,False
```

This tells VB to not wait for the command to return.

https://www.vbsedit.com/html/6f28899c-d653-4555-8a59-49640b0e32ea.asp

Comment: sorry. It does not work. It does not close the vbs or wscript.exe.

Comment: are you sure? can you update your question with an annotated screenshot or recording that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: That’s is what it does. I’ve written oodles of vb scripts. Setting ‘wait’ to false will prevent vb script from blocking while the command runs. You’re missing something or we don’t have all the info. Have you confirmed the batch file is actually running? Have you out any sanity checks in? For instance `wscript.echo “I’m here.”` right after or before the objshell.run so you know if the script actually moved beyond that.

Comment: I have added an update, where the problem is described more exactly.